# Replacing blank values in key value pairs with new values in dictionaries (pythohn 3.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary that stores an arbitrary amount of username and password pairs, but I don't know how to substitute the new passwords for the blank values. Unfortunately, I have to have the username inputs finished before I can ask for the password inputs.

```
dictionary= {}   # blank database
userpassno = int(input("How many username and password pairs?"))    # user input for amount of pairs
for i in range(userpassno):     # loop that runs as many times as the number of pairs
    username = input("Enter username:")     # Username input
    database[username] = None               # No passwords yet
for i in range(userpassno):
    password = input("Enter password:")  # password input
    database[username] = password        # Puts passwords into database
print(database)
```

Comment: What does this mean?  "substitute the new passwords for the blank values"

Comment: I'm sorry I should have been clearer, the key value pair in this particular code is username-password, and the passwords are left blank for the first loop and they need to be replaced by actual values in the 2nd loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list to store all the usernames that the user inputs in the first loop, and then use the stored usernames to assign the password inputs to the corresponding entry in the dict in the second loop:

```
database= {}   # blank database
userpassno = int(input("How many username and password pairs?"))    # user input for amount of pairs
usernames = []
for i in range(userpassno):     # loop that runs as many times as the number of pairs
    usernames.append(input("Enter username:"))     # Username input
for username in usernames:
    database[username] = input("Enter password:")  # password input
print(database)
```

Comment: I was doing that, however, the requirements state that all the usernames need to be entered first and then after the usernames are done, the passwords need to be entered. So, for example, say the user needs to enter 2 user and password pairs, what the output should look like is:
    Enter username
    Enter username
    Enter password
    Enter password
Then i need to relate the two.